# How to use jquery click your browser turn off a layer at any position

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery click your browser turn off a layer at any position?I trying 6 hour is Unsuccessful..

Comment: Hello Edward, got an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hiding an element is pretty straight forward, just select it and call the `hide` method. Example:

```
<script>

$(function(){
  $('#ElementToClick').click(function(){
    $('#ElementToHide').hide();
  });
});

</script>

<div id="ElementToClick">Clicking me...</div>
<div id="ElementToHide">...hides me</div>
```